# Why would ConfidentialClientApplication.GetAccountsAsync intermitantly return null?

Tags: jwt, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0, openid-connect

I'm using example Azure AD Open ID connect authentication code to authenticate my ASP.Net Core web application.

The standard authentication flow works flawlessly but when I try to acquire a JWT through the token acquisition service the call to GetAccountAsync and then GetAccountsAsync fail to return an account.

The crazy part is that it does not always fail.

In Edge, if the credentials are cached and I do not log in GetAccountAsync fails to return an account. If credentials are not cached and I log in, GetAccountAsync  returns an account.

What would cause this?

I noticed that when the credentials are cached the OnAuthorizationCodeReceived is not received and the account is added to the cache here.

```
var handler = options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived;
options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async context =>
{
    var _tokenAcquisition = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITokenAcquisition>();
    await _tokenAcquisition.AddAccountToCacheFromAuthorizationCode(context, options.Scope);
    await handler(context);
};
```

How would these credentials be added to the cache without going through the login as happens when they are cached in the browser?

Comment: Now that I have a better understanding of what's going on here, my question is not correct. The real question is how do I deal with cached credentials. The account information is not available because the authentication never occurred between my app and the identity provider.